# Obtaining only unique combinations of with data from 1 column multiple rows VBA

Tags: vba, excel, combinations, permutation

I know how to create all the possible combinations but I'm having difficulties to obtain only the unique ones.

In my example I have 5 rows of data values (1,2,3,4,5) in `A3:A7`

My goal would be to get all the unique combinations with that data and not have the ones that repeat.

Here is the code that I have right now

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

For i = 3 To 7
Cells(i, 1) = i - 2
Next i

Cells(1, 3) = "number"
Cells(3, 3) = "combinations"

For i = 3 To 7
For Z = 3 To 6
last = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(7, 1)).Copy Destination:=Range(Cells(3, last + 1), Cells(7, last + 1))
temp = Cells(i, 1)
Cells(i, last + 1) = Cells(Z + 1, 1)
Cells(Z + 1, last + 1) = temp
Next Z
Next i

End Sub
```

Here is possible to see what happens in the excel file
[image: Excel representation]

Comment: What is the logic behind the sample data? Also what is the logic in your nested loops, as I don't see the need for copy pasting?

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is to make some random range and see the unique cells, this is some option:

1. Create the range;
2. Put some random values in it;
3. Use the built-in formula for `WorksheetFunction.CountIf()` to see whether the value is unique;
4. If it is unique, color it in Magenta:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GenerateRandoms()

    Dim someRange As Range
    Set someRange = Range("A1:F20")
    someRange.Clear

    Dim myCell As Range

    For Each myCell In someRange
        myCell = MakeRandom(1, 50)
    Next myCell

    Dim someUniqueValues As Range

    For Each myCell In someRange
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(someRange, myCell) = 1 Then
            myCell.Interior.Color = vbMagenta
        End If
    Next myCell

End Sub

Private Function MakeRandom(down As Long, up As Long) As Long
    MakeRandom = CLng((up - down) * Rnd + down)
End Function
```